# php process background

Tags: php, process, background-process

I've a question about this answer
[php execute a background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process/45966#45966)

Can anyone provide me a working simple example to try what the answer explains?

Thanks in advance!

Alberto

Comment: That answer is is wrong in any context other than a shell session, and that failure to complete is an a likely outcome - the spawned process is not dissociated from the session, it merely runs in parallel until the session ends. Are you sure this applies to your scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux box only:

result.php

```
<?php
$cmd = 'for i in {1..5}; do date; sleep 2; done';
$outputfile = '/tmp/result.txt';
$pidfile = '/tmp/result.pid';
exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, $outputfile, $pidfile));
?>
```

in command line:

```
php result.php;
tail /tmp/result.txt; /* to monitor the results, take 10 seconds to complete */
cat /tmp/result.pid   /* the pid registered */
```