# PHP oci timeout?

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

I would like to set a timeout on a query

```
$statement = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($statement); // timeout if this takes over 5 minutes
```

this is was asked before but all the way back in 11 with no solid answer

[Run a sql query with a timeout in PHP or How in PHP, to stop a sql query once already begun?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8039075/run-a-sql-query-with-a-timeout-in-php-or-how-in-php-to-stop-a-sql-query-once-al)

I found this request too from last year
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73038

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [PHP OCI driver](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/3b7e18af789278506131e7f13f54e4b900d939e1/ext/oci8/oci8_statement.c#L546) does not support query time outs (via `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT`) at the interface with the Oracle library. Thus, there is no direct user-land means to accomplish this.

The standard way to do this would be to execute a separate process that itself has a timeout. You might go about it like so:

```
// oci8-exec.php
set_time_limit(300); // 5 minutes
$conn = getDatabaseConnection();
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $_SERVER['argv'][1]);
oci_execute($stmt);
oci_fetch_all($stmt, $rows);
var_export($rows);
```

then in your code do:

```
$rows = shell_exec('oci8-exec.php "select * from foo"');
```

Obviously you would need to have error handling, exit code checking, etc. to make this production ready.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [oci_set_call_timeout](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-set-call-timout.php) for database call timeouts since [oci8 2.2.0](https://pecl.php.net/package/oci8/2.2.0).

```
<?php

$conn = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');
oci_set_call_timeout($conn, 5000);

?>
```